# Linux: copy ".svn" directories recursively

Tags: linux, debian

I know there are dozen of questions about similar topcis but I still can't beat this up.

I need to copy all `.svn` directories recursively from `/var/foo` to `/var/foo2` on a Debian machine:

```
/var/www/foo/.svn
/var/www/foo/bar/.svn
...
```

I tried these two commands without success:

```
find /var/foo -name ".svn" -type f -exec cp {} ./var/foo2 \;
find /var/foo -name ".svn" -type d -exec cp {} /var/foo2 \;
```

Once only the `svn` directory right inside `foo` is copied, while another time nothing is copied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given following file structure:

```
./
./a/
./a/test/
./a/test/2
./b/
./b/3
./test/
./test/1
```

Running following script in the directory to be copied:

```
find -type d -iname test -exec sh -c 'mkdir -p "$(dirname ~/tmp2/{})"; cp -r {}/ ~/tmp2/{}' \;
```

Should copy all test directories to `~/tmp2/`.

Points of interest:

- Directories are copied to the destination on a one-by-one basis
- Parent directories are created in advance so that `cp` doesn't complain about target not existing
- Rather than just `cp`, `cp -r` is used
- The whole command is wrapped with `sh -c` so that operations on {} such as `dirname` can be performed (so that the shell expands it for each directory separately, rather than expanding it once during calling the `find`)

Resulting structure in `~/tmp2`:

```
./
./a/
./a/test/
./a/test/2
./test/
./test/1
```

So all you should need to do is to replace `test` with `.svn` and `~/tmp2` with directory of choice. **Just remember about running it in the source directory, instead of using absolute paths.**

Comment: What an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I find that using `tar` for such operations makes the code often much more readable:

```
$ mkdir /var/www/foo2
$ cd /var/www/foo2
$ find ../foo/ -type d -name .svn -exec tar c \{\} \+ | \
         tar x --strip-components=1
```

`find` will list all directories named `.svn`, and call `tar` to create (`c`) an archive file (that is sent to `stdout`) with all these directories. the archive on stdout is then extracted (`x`) by another tar instance in the target directory. the relative path portion (`../`) is automatically removed by the archiving tar, but since we also want to remove the first path component (`foo/`) we need to add `--strip-components`.

Note: This will only work if you do not have *very many* `.svn` directories you want to copy (more than `$(getconf ARG_MAX)-2`, which on my system is more than 200000).